# Kafka Streams 2.3.0 store get-rate metric not found in JMX

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

We've upgraded our Kafka Streams application form 2.2.0 to 2.3.0 (for the InMemoryWindowStore) and we were monitoring some metrics via JMX and after upgrading to 2.3.0 getting State Store metric `get-rate` throws a AttributeNotFoundException. Has anyone else has seen this issue? In the documentation there is no mention of it being removed..

Thank you

Comment: Did you update the metric name correct? RocksDB stores use `rocksdb-window-state` while the new in-memory stores use `in-memory-window-state`?

Comment: No I didnt. We're querying JMX with pattern `kafka.streams:type=stream-*-state-metrics,*` and then for each object found with that pattern, getting the metric.

Something like:

`final String OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN = "kafka.streams:type=stream-*-state-metrics,*";

for (ObjectInstance object : platformMBeanServer.queryMBeans(
                    new ObjectName(OBJECT_NAME_PATTERN), null)) {

        final Object attribute = 
platformMBeanServer.getAttribute(getObjectName(), "get-rate");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in the metric names of read operations in key-value, window, and session stores. Key-value stores record read operations in metrics prefixed by `get-`, whereas window and session stores record read operations in metrics prefixed by `fetch-`. Unfortunately, the documentation about the metrics does not mention `fetch` at all.

In your case, you should look for `fetch-rate` since you are using a window store.

I opened the following ticket to document these inconsistencies https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8906

This issue was also there in 2.2, so I am wondering why you did not get this error before.